# Titanium Adding custom template to a listview

Tags: listview, titanium-alloy

I'm currently building an application with Titanium studio and Alloy. 
In one of my Windows, I'm trying to dynamically add ListItem in a listView by pressing some button (allowing the user to retrieve an image or some file).

I need to add some listItem with some particular structures : An image supposed to show the dataType, a label for the file name, and another image to delete the listItem.
Here is my template :

**ligneFichier.xml**

```
<Alloy>
<ItemTemplate name="ligneFichier" id="ligneFichier">
     <View class="item-container">               
         <ImageView bindId="typeDonnee" />
         <Label bindId="nomFichier" />  
         <ImageView bindId="supprimer" />
     </View>
</ItemTemplate>
</Alloy>
```

And then, in the controller of my page :

**myController.js**

```
var data = [];
        var tmp = {
            typeDonnee : {
                image : '/images/image.png'
            },
            nomFichier : {
                text : event.media.file.name
            },
            supprimer : {
                image : '/images/supprimer.png'                 
            }
            //I tried to use this line :
            //template: 'ligneFichier',
            //But it tells me that template is undefined
        };
        data.push(tmp);

        //My listView
        $.listeFichiers.sections[0].items = $.listeFichiers.sections[0].items.concat(data);
```

So I tried to link the template with alloy directly :

```
       <ListView id="listeFichiers" height="100" headerTitle="" template="ligneFichier">
            <ListSection id="photo" headerTitle="">

            </ListSection>
            <ListSection id="audio" headerTitle="">

            </ListSection>
        </ListView>
```

But, when I add a line, it doesn't use my template, it doesn't even find the text, it only write 'label'.
And then, in the console, there is that message :

> Please use 'properties' binding for builtInTemplate

So I tried to replace the binding name by 'Properties' but with no success...
Does this mean something to someone? Do not hesitate to ask for some precisions or to tell me if I forgot some sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that alloy can't recognize your template because it was defined in a separate file.
Try to define it in the same file like this :

```
 <ListView id="listeFichiers" height="100" headerTitle="" defaultItemTemplate='ligneFichier'>
  <Templates>
   <ItemTemplate name="ligneFichier" id="ligneFichier">
     <View class="item-container">               
        <ImageView bindId="typeDonnee" />
        <Label bindId="nomFichier" />  
        <ImageView bindId="supprimer" />
     </View>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </Templates>
   <ListSection headerTitle="Title">
     <ListItem typeDonnee:image="yourimage.png" nomFichier:text="FileName" supprimer:image="supprimer.png" />
   </ListSection>
 </ListView>
```

EDIT : You can use require to add your template :

in templateName.xml :

```
 <Alloy>
   <ItemTemplate name="ligneFichier" id="ligneFichier">
     <View class="item-container">               
        <ImageView bindId="typeDonnee" />
        <Label bindId="nomFichier" />  
        <ImageView bindId="supprimer" />
     </View>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </Alloy>
```

then add it to your listview templates

```
 <ListView id="listeFichiers" height="100" headerTitle="" defaultItemTemplate='ligneFichier'>
  <Templates>
   <Require src="templateName"/>
  </Templates>
   <ListSection headerTitle="Title">
     <ListItem typeDonnee:image="yourimage.png" nomFichier:text="FileName" supprimer:image="supprimer.png" />
   </ListSection>
 </ListView>
```

I have tested it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm facing the same issue, litteraly no differences...
However, I see that you declared a listItem explicitly in the section, even if it's not what I'm looking for, I tried to but still no luck.
EDIT: Actually, the explicit declaration work if you use the 'defaultItemTemplate' attribute in the <ListView> tag.
And it works! Edit your question to add this attribute and I accept it :)

Comment: PS: There is no way to get the templates to work from a separate file? That would be prettier if I need to re-use it somewhere else in the futur

Comment: it seems that require works fine see this [example](https://github.com/LHIOUI/listviewRequire)

Comment: Hi @Coyote Can you tell me how to bind switch into list. I have a switch and i want it to display on a row in my list. Please help me ?

Comment: ask a question and put the link here i will see if i can help you.